# Aem Instance is not stating up

Tags: aem

Aem Author instance is not coming up after the automatic backup process.  We have automatic backup process scheduled daily at 10:00 Pm PST. We are running a Shell script(`backuprepo.sh`) which in-turn triggers the stop.sh to bring the server down, do the backup process and then trigger the start.sh script to start the instance again.

The instance is brought down, but sometimes it is not started with the start script and has to be started manually. We have noticed that the below crx java process is not killed when the server is stopped though the stop script.

> adobeam6 8454210       1   2 22:27:57      - 187:34 java -server
>   -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xmx4096m -Doak.queryLimitInMemory=500000 -Doak.queryLimitReads=100000 -Dupdate.limit=250000 -Doak.fastQuerySize=true -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Djava.awt.headless=true -javaagent:/app/AEM6/author/crx-quickstart/app/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Djava.io.tmpdir=/app/AEM6/author/tmp -Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles -Dsling.run.modes=author,sit -jar crx-quickstart/app/cq-quickstart-6.0.0-standalone.jar start -c
>   crx-quickstart -i launchpad -p 4502
>   -Dsling.properties=conf/sling.properties

So we have to manually kill the process and trigger the start script to start the instance. Trying to figure out why the server is not stopped properly sometimes and why the above mentioned process is not killed even when the server is stopped through stop script.

We have verified the error logs which only stated the Instance has stopped as last Info.

Below are the steps executed by the backuprepo.sh script:

1)Trigger the stop.sh script

2)Wait for the server to stop automatically and backup process to complete.

3)After the backupprocess is complete, check if the server is started automatically.

4)Sometimes the server is not started automatically which is the issue.

Attached the start.sh and stop.sh scripts.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B67j43IdLr8mLXVCWTYxd1NialE
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B67j43IdLr8mbDNPWndRdE5SWEE

**Question**:

1. Do we have any scenarios when we stop the AEM server, the crx java background process would still be running?
2. Any clues for our case which is preventing the java process to be release when the stop script is triggered?